# Today and Yesterday's date at midnight in specific format

Tags: powershell, date

I need to get today and yesterdays date at midnight in the following format:

`08/05/2018 00:00`

The best I seem to be able to get is this:

```
get-date -Uformat "%D %R" -Hour 0 -Minute 00
```

`08/05/18 00:00`

I fail miserably when trying to get yesterday at midnight.

```
(Get-Date -UFormat "%s" -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-1)
```

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named AddDays.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + (Get-Date -UFormat "%s" -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-1)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with the `-UFormat` option:

```
Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -UFormat "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

This produces the following output:

```
08/05/2018 00:00
```

The error you are seeing is due to the fact that you are invoking `AddDays` method over a string. To manipulate the date, you can do the following:

```
(Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00).AddDays(-1) | Get-Date -UFormat "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

This will produce the desired output.

Answer (score 6):

To get a date(time) at midnight you can use :

```
(Get-Date).Date
```

Or

```
[datetime]::Today
```

To format it according to your requirement can be tricky if your current date format has a different separator (as is the case here).

```
> (get-date).Date.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
08-05-2018 00:00
```

The `.ToString()` method overrides the separator; to take the slash literal you have to escape it with a backslash:

```
> (get-date).Date.ToString('MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm')
08/05/2018 00:00
```

Or use:

```
> (get-date).Date.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
08/05/2018 00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

## Code

```
(Get-Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00")
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00")
```

You have to perform the `AddDays` to the *date* while it's still a date (and not a string that looks like a date).

## Result

```
05/08/2018 00:00
04/08/2018 00:00
```

---

## For *American* format

`dd/MM/yyyy` simply becomes `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

For today use `[DateTime]::Today` and format it with `ToString()`

```
[Datetime]::Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

For Yesterday, just add `AddDays(-1)`

```
[Datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)|Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
```